# How to prepare data for passing to $X{} expression instead of using CONCAT SQL

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to use the `concat` function of sql in the `$X{}` expression:

```
($X{IN,(CONCAT(vtiger_usersAccounts.first_name,' ',vtiger_usersAccounts.last_name)),user)
```

I have errors, but how can I do something like that?

Comment: What happens when you try it? I was able to get this working in Oracle for one of my queries: 
$X{IN, GROUP||CLASS||SUBCLASS, full_subclass}

Comment: error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{IN,(CONCAT(vtiger_usersAccounts.first_name,' ',vtiger_usersAccounts.last_name))' at line 1

Comment: Alex, what do you mean with prepare expression with help of parameter?

Comment: What about:
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name) AS name FROM table) WHERE $X{IN, name, user}

Comment: Normally my query is something like:trim(case when (vtiger_usersPotentials.last_name NOT LIKE '') then CONCAT(vtiger_usersPotentials.first_name,' ',vtiger_usersPotentials.last_name) else vtiger_groupsPotentials.groupname end) = 'USERNAME'

Now I want the selected value from the input control (collection) instead of USERNAME

Answer (score 1):

Try using a semi-colon (or pipe) delimiter in the $X function, then it will be parsed correctly:

```
$X{IN;CONCAT(vtiger_usersAccounts.first_name,' ',vtiger_usersAccounts.last_name);user)
```

One other thing to note if you're playing with this in iReport, everytime you change the report in the Gui (lets say you resize a column) the sql will revert back to the comma delimiter, seems to be an annoying bug in iReport.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(vtiger_usersAccounts.first_name,' ',vtiger_usersAccounts.last_name) as name FROM table WHERE $X{IN, name, user}
```

The working sample for *HSQLDB*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ..>
    <parameter name="cities" class="java.util.Collection">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList("Dallas 2 Upland Pl.", "Chicago 202 College Av.")]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, CONCAT(city, CONCAT(' ', street)) as name FROM address WHERE $X{IN, name, cities}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

***Note:*** In this sample I've used the *`CONCAT(value1, CONCAT(' ', value2))`* expression instead of your expression *`CONCAT(value1, ' ', value2)`*.

---

You can find more info about using `$X{}` syntax at [Query Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#query) post.